# 'default' showing up so, procedure or function has too many arguments specified;

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

## Overall Goal

Re-write portion of web site exposed to longtime clients that still relies upon SQL query execution of the format and is currently working as expected:

```
SQLQuery = "exec spNewPayments " & "162611"
  Set rsPmts = objConnection.Execute(SQLQuery)
```

Where 162611 is an integer. The goal then is to parameterize query using *command* object and adding parameters using *.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter* technique.

Additionally, secondary goal is to eventually *add* additional parameters to limit the scope of the query, but I haven't even gotten that far in this post.

### Problem

When running query using *objConnection.Execute*, the stored procedure runs as expected with one parameter, an integer (see above). When running query using *recordsource.Open command* I receive message:

```
  spNewPayments has too many arguments specified
  Code: 80040E14
```

The stored procedure is created using:

```
USE [maindb]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spNewPayments] @claim_id int = NULL AS
select *
FROM dbo.objectTest co
WHERE co.foreign_id = @claim_id;

GO
```

The VBScript that I am currently using as a test is:

```
Dim strCnxn 
strCnxn = "DSN=myDSN"
Dim objConnection
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")  
objConnection.Mode = acModeRead
objConnection.Open strCnxn

Dim cmd
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Dim rsPmts 
Set rsPmts = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
With cmd
.ActiveConnection = objConnection

.CommandType = 4
.CommandText = "spNewPayments"

.Parameters.Refresh

.Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@claim_id", 3, , , 162611)

End With

rsPmts.Open cmd
rsPmts.Close 

Set rsPmts = Nothing
 Set objConnection = Nothing
 Set cmd = Nothing
```

As mentioned, when I run this, I get: "Procedure or function spNewPayments has too many arguments specified"  It occurs in the line `rsPmts.Open cmd`

I trace using Profiler in the SQL Server MS to see how the server is responding, and I see:

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=180150003
declare @p3 int
set @p3=8
declare @p4 int
set @p4=1
declare @p5 int
set @p5=2
exec sp_ddopen @p1 output,N'sp_sproc_columns',@p3 output,@p4 output,@p5 output,N'spNewPayments',NULL,NULL,NULL
select @p1, @p3, @p4, @p5
go
exec sp_cursorfetch 180150003,2,1,1
go
exec sp_cursorfetch 180150003,2,1,1
go
exec sp_cursorfetch 180150003,2,1,1
go
exec sp_cursorclose 180150003
go
exec spNewPayments default,162611
go
```

Aha!  It appears it is passing *two* parameters, the first parameter as *default*.  Huh?  What is that?  How does it get in there?

Obviously, this is caused by having too many parameters, but I don't think my code is adding two parameters, just one.

This error also seems to come up when people are inadvertently in a loop, but I haven't even gotten to my loop yet.  I plan to loop through the *recordsource* later.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Stored Procedure in Classical ASP .. execute and get results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21915874/using-stored-procedure-in-classical-asp-execute-and-get-results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.Parameter.Refresh()` causes ADO to request the parameters from SQL Server which is an overhead you can see in the SQL Profiler trace you have provided. Calling this method populates the `.Parameters` collection automatically but is not recommended for production due to the server request being made to populate the collection on every execution.

These lines in the trace are due to the `.Parameters.Refresh` call;

```sql
-- Declaration and setting of temporary varibles
declare @p1 int
set @p1=180150003
declare @p3 int
set @p3=8
declare @p4 int
set @p4=1
declare @p5 int
set @p5=2
/*
Execution of sp_sproc_columns to get the expected parameters from the
spNewPayments stored procedure (see https://stackoverflow.com/q/7903268/692942).
*/
exec sp_ddopen @p1 output,N'sp_sproc_columns',@p3 output,@p4 output,@p5 output,N'spNewPayments',NULL,NULL,NULL
select @p1, @p3, @p4, @p5
go
-- Use cursor to loop through results.
exec sp_cursorfetch 180150003,2,1,1
go
exec sp_cursorfetch 180150003,2,1,1
go
exec sp_cursorfetch 180150003,2,1,1
go
-- Close the cursor.
exec sp_cursorclose 180150003
go
```

The reason for the error is because you then manually add the parameter using the `.Parameters.Append()` and the `CreateParameter()` methods. This would work fine and would be my recommended approach, if you hadn’t called `Refresh()` first in effect doubling up the parameter `@claim_id` in the `Parameters` collection causing it to have `Too many arguments`.

So, the fix in your code example is to remove;

```vb
.Parameters.Refresh
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [Using Stored Procedure in Classical ASP .. execute and get results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21944948/692942)
- [Error trying to call stored procedure with prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21698468/692942)
- [Using METADATA to Import DLL Constants](https://web.archive.org/web/20210417073339/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110199-1.shtml) *(If you are using Classic ASP would highly recommend this approach to use named constants)*

Answer (score -1):

There are two things I normally look at that should fix this.

The first is set the [CommandType property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/commandtype-property-ado) of the `ADODB.Command` object to `adCmdStoredProc` like this:

```
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
```

But you may have already done that on this line:

```
.CommandType = 4
```

I'm just not sure from memory what value the `adCmdStoredProc` constant has.

The other is putting the placeholder directly in the command text:

```
.CommandText = "spNewPayments @claim_id"
```

This goes best with the `adCmdText` CommandType, and is not usually needed or helpful if `CommandType` was set to `adCmdStoredProc`, so this is a one-or-the-other situation. I've seen it done both ways effectively.

Looking again, you might want `.Parameters.Clear` rather than `.Parameters.Refresh`, but as you just created the object you shouldn't need either and it's been a *very* long time since I've done old-school ADO.

Comment: When I used `cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc` I get the error `ADODB.Command (13, 2) : Arguments are of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with one another.` I think this was indicating that the constant was not available, so I read here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/commandtypeenum?view=sql-server-2017 and assigned it to 4 instead. .Parameters.Clear gives "Object doesn't support this properly or method: 'Parameters.Clear'"

Comment: When I try the placeholder and CommandType =1, I get `[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@claim_id"` which seems to be returned from the SQL Server itself.  Interestingly enough, I did get it to work by  inserting `cmd.Parameters.Delete 1` before my `cmd.Parameters.Append` line.  It returns the desired recordset and everything.  It's as if there is a secret hidden default parameter attached to the object when it is created and I have to delete that first before appending to it.

Comment: Yes, CommandType=1 should work when you also change the command text to include the placeholder, like this: `.CommandText = "spNewPayments @claim_id"`. Not sure where the extra parameter was coming from. Might be useful or instructional to print a few debug messages with the parameter name and type.

Comment: @CarloTex, try removing the `.Parameters.Refresh` from your original code. That populates the parameters collection from meta-data whereas you are adding the parameter manually.

Comment: Don’t use `Refresh` as it causes a server round trip to populate the `Parameters` collection *(as can be seen in the SQL Profiler trace in the question)*. The error occurs because you `Append` to the parameter collection after it has been refreshed. If you just wanted to set the values to be sent you would use `.Parameters(“@claim_id”).Value = 162611`. At the moment it’s being appended again which is causing the `too many arguments specified` error. In the code above removing the `.Parameters.Refresh` will fix it.

Comment: There’s is nothing wrong with the `CommandType` except would recommend using the Named Constants from ADO so it should be `adCmdStoredProc`. You only use placeholders in `adCmdText` because it is designed for dynamic SQL execution.

Comment: Also the only placeholder that works with `adCmdText` is `?` you can’t use `@claim_id`.