# C# app passing weird SQL param values

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm working on an app written in C# (VS2013). It's calling a stored procedure in SQL Server. It's passing a bunch of input parameters, plus four output parameters.

My problem is that one of these output parameters is getting passed with a value that I'm not setting.

This is what SQL Server Profiler records as the procedure call. I've replaced the actual parameter names with generic names just for asking this question.

```
declare @p51 int
set @p51 = 300000

declare @p52 int
set @p52 = NULL

declare @p53 int
set @p53 = 7776

declare @p54 int
set @p54 = NULL

exec [dbo].[proc_name] (input param list is here)
     @outparam1 = @p51 output, @outparam2 = @p52 output,
     @outparam3 = @p53 output, @outparam4 = @p54 output
```

`@outparam3/@p53` is the issue. It shouldn't have a value. It's being created with a null value like this (even though as an output parameter that shouldn't be necessary):

```
var spParam3 = new SqlParameter("@outparam3", SqlDbType.Int);
spParam3.Value = DBNull.Value;
```

There's nothing between that line of code, and the stored procedure execution, that's setting a different value for the parameter. I've set a breakpoint on the `ExecuteNonQuery()` call, checked the parameter list, and that parameter was still null.

I'm completely lost on why its value is getting set to 7776. Yes, that number is a code used throughout the app, but I can't tell how or why this parameter is getting set to that value.

Any thoughts on where this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A stored procedure in the sql server.

Comment: This is technically right but I didn't understand it until I found this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2198715/stored-procedure-output-parameters-in-sql-server-profiler

Answer (score 0):

```
@outparam3=@p53
```

@p53 = 7776

thats why the value you get/insert in table is 7776

Comment: What I don't understand is where that's coming from. I can't see anywhere in the process (setting up the stored procedure call, setting the parameters, executing the call) where I'm assigning anything the value of 7776.